# Valores da tabela sendo truncados

Tags: sql

Fiz código na parte de declaração do numero real que palavra saldo que ele vai receber um numero com 6 dígitos e 2 duas casas decimais depois da virgula, só que todos os valores que eu insiro são truncados, como resolver ?

```
create database uri
default character set utf8
default collate utf8_general_ci;

use uri;

create table pessoas(

 id int not null auto_increment,
 nome varchar(30),
 rua varchar(30),
 cidade varchar(30),
 regiao char(3),
 saldo decimal(6,2),
 primary key(id)

) default charset utf8;

insert into pessoas values
('1','Pedro Augusto da Rocha','Rua Pedro Carlos Hoffman','Porto Alegre','RS','700,00'),
('2','Antonio Carlos Mamel','Av. Pinheiros','Belo Horizonte','MG','3500,50'),
('3','Luiza Augusta Mhor','Rua Salto Grande','Niteroi','RJ','4000,00'),
('4','Jane Ester','Av 7 de setembro','Erechim','RS','800,00'),
('5','Marcos Antônio dos Santos','Av Farrapos','Porto Alegre','RS','4250,25');
SELECT nome FROM pessoas WHERE regiao = 'RS';
```

Comment: Truncados como?

Comment: Troque as vírgulas por ponto antes de inserir no banco.

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto

Answer (score 2):

Você deve utilizar ponto(.) e não virgula(,) para separar o decimal, o mysql não utiliza o padrão brasileiro.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21d68c/2

Answer (score 2):

Troque "," por "." pois o campo é do tipo decimal(só aceita numero e o separador para casas decimais é o ponto)

Exemplo:

```
insert into pessoas values
('1','Pedro Augusto da Rocha','Rua Pedro Carlos Hoffman','Porto Alegre','RS','700.00')
```